# Passing mongoose object to puppeeter's evalute() function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, puppeteer

I am trying to pass mongoose object to evaluate function during **scraping** with puppeeteer and nodejs. Here is the code of the mongoose Model i am using :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ArticleModel = new schema({
    
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    url: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
    },

    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleModel);
```

And here is the code of puppeeter's evaluate function :

```
var res = await page.evaluate((article)=>{
          
          article.title="article title";
          article.url="article url";
          article.description ="article description";
          article.save(function(err,result)=>{
              if(err){
                 console.log(err);
              }

              if(result){
                console.log(result._id);
              }
          });

      },new ArticleModel());
```

When i run this code i get this Error message : **Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: article.save is not a function**

Can someone help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Objects are serialized when are being passed to chromium through the evaluate function. Si `article` will have no `save` function on the chromium side.

Comment: @hardkoded Thanks for your answer. So how can i do to save date into the database throught Mongoose object within evaluate() function ?

Comment: You can't. But, you could make the evaluate return the values you need to save the article on the node side.

Comment: @hardkoded Thanks a lot for your answers.